# Round negative integer quotient towards negative infinity

Tags: swift, rounding

It appears that integer divisions in Swift round towards zero rather than towards the lower number. This means, for instance, that `-1 / 2` will be 0 instead of -1.

Is there a way to tell Swift to round towards the lower number? I know how I can "simulate" it, but if there's a native solution, I'd rather use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own operator like this:

```
infix operator </> { associativity left }
func </> (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(floor(Double(a) / Double(b)))
}
```

so that you don't have to type that absurd expression. I'm proposing `</>`, but of course you can choose your own.

If you don't like creating operators, then use it as a normal function:

```
func div (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(floor(Double(a) / Double(b)))
}
```

Last, but personally I would **not** use it, you can **redefine the division operator**:

```
func / (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(floor(Double(a) / Double(b)))
}
```

and in that case it will applied to all divisions - be aware of side effects though

Answer (score 0):

The floor function rounds down so if you do `floor(Float(a)/Float(b))` it should work.

Comment: That would be `Int(floor(Float(a)/Float(b)))`, though. Definitely not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 0):

The backup solution that I have involves a new operator `-/`. The math doesn't involve shuffling back and forth between doubles and integers, which avoids some edge cases with very large numbers. On the other hand, this can overflow instead if both `denominator` and `numerator` are very large negative numbers, and I'm not sure what happens exactly if `denominator` is negative.

```
infix operator -/ {
   precedence 150
   associativity left
}

func -/ (numerator: Int, denominator: Int) -> Int {
   if numerator < 0 {
       return (numerator - (denominator - 1)) / denominator
   }
   return numerator / denominator
}
```

Any solution written in terms of Swift will probably end up with its share of issues if you want to emulate C behavior. Another possibility would be to include a tiny `divide` function in the bridging header and implement the operator with it.